# ExtJs 4.1 grid grouping feature - preventing 'group' keyword from appearing in the heading

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-grid

I am using ExtJs  4.1 grid and have added group feature. In the store I have specified the groupField and grouping feature is working fine. But when the grid renders, the group header is shown as **Group: Group-Name**". How Can I prevent 'Group' keyword from appearing in the group header (which is highlighted on below image).

[image]

```
Ext.require(['Ext.data.*', 'Ext.grid.*']);
Ext.onReady(function() {
   Ext.regModel('Teams', {
       fields: ['name', 'sport']
   });

   var teamStore = new Ext.data.Store({
       model: 'Teams',
       sorters: ['sport','name'],
       groupField: 'sport',
       data: [
           { name: 'Aaron', sport: 'Table Tennis' },
           { name: 'Aaron', sport: 'Football' },
           { name: 'Abe', sport: 'Basketball' },
           { name: 'Tommy', sport: 'Football' },
           { name: 'Tommy', sport: 'Basketball' },
           { name: 'Jamie', sport: 'Table Tennis' },
           { name: 'Brian', sport: 'Basketball' },
           { name: 'Brian', sport: 'Table Tennis' }
       ]
   });

   var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
       renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
       store: teamStore,
       width: 400,
       height: 300,
       title: 'Sports Teams',
       features: [{
           ftype: 'grouping'
       }],
       headers: [{
           text: 'Name',
           flex: 1,
           dataIndex: 'name'
       },{
           text: 'Sport',
           dataIndex: 'sport'
       }]
   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
features: [{
        ftype: 'grouping',
        groupHeaderTpl: '{name}'
    }]
```